# Can I execute a php file from my functions.php in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using a function to execute a code that sends an email with an attachment.
This function is hooked on to a filter from woocommerce.

I'd like to rebuild this function to execute the code from an external php file.
Is this possible in Wordpress?

The reason I want to execute it from an external script is because I want some more functionality, the sender of the email and the attachment are generated from sessions.

In my child theme's function.php-

```
function send_invoice () 
{
    $attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/mytheme/invoices/invoice.pdf' );
    wp_mail( 'targetmail@domain.com', 'Attachment test', 'The message', 'header', $attachments);
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'send_invoice' );
```

Is there a way to execute a php file from my functions.php?

Further elaboration:
I'm trying to convert the previous script to something like:
Functions.php

```
function execute_send_invoice () {
    send_invoice();
}   
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'execute_send_invoice' );
```

And then the code for send_invoice(); somewhere outside my functions.php, for instance, in myscript.php which is located in my template directory.

Comment: If the file is included, wordpress or not, you can just call the function like normal

Comment: So I don't have to link the new php file, if I just write my function there I can call it in my functions.php?
BTW can you define, "included"? Do I have to link it manually, or is a file included when it is in my theme directory?

Comment: see my answer for an explanation. With wordpress, `functions.php` is automatically included when the theme is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needless to say, you should be very careful about running external scripts in PHP.

If there isn't some kind of preparsing done by wordpress before executing your PHP files, there are two main ways to run external code. Using the first, you must further enclose the PHP in `<?php ?>` tags, but it's my personal suggestion.

```
include('full_or_relative_php_path_to_file.php');
```

or

```
eval(file_get_contents('full_or_relative_php_path_to_file.php'));
```

Comment: I am facing same problem here which file you have included and how.

Answer (score 0):

If the `functions.php` file is inside the theme that is currently active, it is included by default. Therefore, you can access and call the function like you normally would (as if it was defined on the same page that you will be calling the function from).

[see here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained)

Comment: That is the functionality I'm trying to achieve, only backwards.
My goal is to have the function like this:

        function execute_send_invoice() {
  send_invoice();
 } 
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'execute_send_invoice' );

And have the code for send_invoice(); outside of my functions.php file.

Comment: In that case, use [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) within functions.php to add the PHP file that contains `send_invoice()`.